# What kind of bug did I squish?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I saw a bug swimming through my carpet, and promptly squished it. I had never seen this kind of bug before, and wanted to find out what it is, so that I can assess it's danger to my house and family, and know how to responsibly take care of it. However, my dog gobbled it up before I could take a photograph, so all I have to go by is a mental image:

- 1.5-2.5 inches long (3-6cm)
- 2-3 segmented body, with a smaller head, and over 3/4 of it's length was the back segment
- Mandibles/Pincers at one end of the body (I can't remember which)
- I think it only had 6 or so legs.
- The dog made a disgruntled face when she ate it, so I think it could have tasted badly, or bit/stung her tongue as she ate it.
- I believe it was two colors, with a pale colored section and a reddish-brown section, although I can't remember their locations.

I live in the Northwestern US, and have three trees on my lot: two maples and a boxelder. The house was built in 1954 and has a crawlspace foundation.

Comment: Did it look like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_coach_horse_beetle

Comment: Or possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earwig?

Comment: @arboviral it looked more like an earwig, I'm familiar with those, but it was at least twice as long as any I've seen, and the coloring was different.

Comment: Okay; I can't think of anything obvious but if you can add details of the colouring that might help others.

Comment: @arboviral -  I've added in what I can remember about color

Comment: this i going to be very hard without pictures! some beetle larvae have "pincers" in front, maybe check out some carabid larvae?